# String comparison not returning correct result

Tags: java, string

So I am building a simple user authentication system, users will input their name into username and password fields and then the code should test what the user enters against a database. I have used a string comparator to do this but it does not execute code in the if statement when correct user and pass are fed through it.

Here is a snippet of the code

```
Boolean authpassed = false
while(rs.next() && (authpassed == false)){

         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         String first = rs.getString("first");
         String last = rs.getString("last");
         String username = rs.getString("username");
         String password = rs.getString("password");


         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.print(", Last: " + last);
         System.out.print(", Username: " + username);
         System.out.println(", Password: " + password);

         if((authuser == username) && (authpass == password) ) {
             System.out.println("Logged In!");
             authpassed = true;
         }
      }
```

When code is executed with correct login details the "Logged in" is not displayed?

Thanks for having a look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use method `equals` not `==` operator: the former compares the *contents* whereas the latter only compares the values of the *references*.

Comment: @MartinFrank I just edited but Bathsheba was faster, thanks!